# tab bar item not showing in storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitabbaritem

I'm trying to add a tab bar controller on an application, and it works fine: I can switch between pages and use the tab bar when I try the app. But I cant see the tab bar items in the storyboard, therefore I cant edit them (I need to set a name and a icon for each item, like "home", "settings").

Here's a picture of the storyboard:
[image]

As you can see the tab bar is gray, and I'm expecting something like this where we can see the items:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a few minutes and after restarting Xcode many times the problem solved itself.

I guess it was a Xcode bug then.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried dragging a Tab Bar Item from the Object Library into the view controllers? It looks like that's what's missing.

[image]

Comment: I'v tried but it did not work. Nevertheless the problem solve itself after a while, I still dont know why. It's a xcode bug I guess